# Can'nt add data to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to add a new user to the database with the next user id of last user's ID but its not happening.

```
function addNewUser($addUserName, $addUserEmail, $addUserPassword, $addUserAuthLevel){
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "admin";
$dbPassword = "d4shb5w";
$dbName = "masterDatabase";
$connection = mysqli_connect($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPassword, $dbName);

//test if connection occurred
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "(" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")");
};

//adding new userInformation into database
$queryLastUserId = "SELECT * FROM userlogindetails ORDER BY userId DESC ";
$LastUserId = mysqli_query($connection, $queryLastUserId);
if($id=mysqli_fetch_assoc($LastUserId)){
    $userId=$id["userId"]+1;

}
$userName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$addUserName);
$userEmailId = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$addUserEmail);
$userPassword = $addUserPassword;
$passwordHash = password_hash($userPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$userAuthLevel= $addUserAuthLevel;
$queryNewUser = "INSERT INTO userlogindetails(userId, userName, userEmailId, userPassword, userLoginTime, userAuthLevel) VALUE ($userId,'$userName', '$userEmailId', '$passwordHash', Now(),'$userAuthLevel')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $queryNewUser);
if($result){
    mysqli_close($connection);
    return "Success "/*.$userId*/;
}else{
    mysqli_close($connection);
    return "Failed "/*.$userId*/;
}
}
```

But when I assign usedId statically then it works fine.
What is the problem in the code?

Comment: Why isn't the user id the primary key and an auto increment field? Then you wouldn't need to worry about getting the last on and adding one to it.

Comment: Use error checking, something you're not doing.

Comment: To add to @slapyo's comment, this will lead to problems when you receive more than one requests at the same time.

Comment: Check the database to confirm the primary key is an integer data type.

Comment: Now change your password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `MAX` function in a PHP function to get the value. This is a better practice.

```
function getMaxID($db){
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT MAX(userId) FROM userlogindetails;");
    return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)["MAX(userId)"];
}
```

Note: I agree with the comments thus far: You should set the primary key to be auto-incrementing. That is an even better practice. MySQL workbench is a great (free) place to start, if you're not yet familiar with data structures.

Answer (score 0):

All this can be done with simply making the id auto_increment in the database. Edit your table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a default value to your $userId variable (e.g. $userId = 1; at the beginning of the function).
If you don't initialize it and in your table there is no users your code will crash.